# Is it possible to extend the set of persistent collections recognized by NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, collections

Suppose I wish to inherit PersistentGenericBag, so that the actual type of my collection property is my custom type, which derives from PersistentGenericBag.

I see two possible ways to achieve this:

- Introduce a new XML keyword, like mybag and somehow register my collection type with NHibernate to associated it with the mybag keyword.
- Override the default logic of associating a collection type with an XML keyword to let NHibernate associated my custom collection type with the well known bag XML keyword.

I am not sure if either is possible, so I would like to get any more information on the subject.

Thanks.

Comment: There could by plenty of reasons. For instance, you want it implement INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: Anyway, I think I have found my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer - utilize the collection-type attribute of bag,map, etc...
[This post](http://analog-man.blogspot.com/2007/01/bridge-gap-between-your-nhibernate.html) helped me to get started. Hope it will yield the desired results.